# Simple Swing tool which displays a few procedurally generated dungeon levels

Tags: java, beginner

I've been teaching myself Java programming. I thought it would be an interesting exercise to program a simple utility for procedurally generating dungeon levels. This program creates a small, random number of dungeon levels and displays them via clicking a `JComboBox` that switches between custom panels extended from `JPanel`. Currently, the program generates rooms, draws them on the screen, shows whether the room is lit or dark (white versus dark gray), whether there's treasure (yellow dots), and monsters if any ("#M" tags).

Originally, I was going to code it such that rooms would be placed only between existing rooms but when I saw the result of letting rooms overlap, I liked it so much I decided to let it be. However, overlapping rooms should be merged into single rooms. I would like to implement that eventually but would like to make sure I'm on the right track first.

Besides that, what else could I do to better follow Java conventions? Do the different classes make logical sense for what I'm trying to accomplish here? This program does work as presented; however, I can think of several other things I'd love to add to it. Finally, once I get the room merging implemented, would a graph data structure be appropriate, with the rooms as nodes, and the exits/tunnels as edges? If not, any hint of how I should handle that would be very welcome.

**Room.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Room {

    //a 1xn is essentially a tunnel, not a room so 
    //minimum size in either direction must be at least two grid units
    private static final int MIN_ROOM_WIDTH = 2;
    private static final int MIN_ROOM_HEIGHT = 2;

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private boolean isLit;
    private int numMonsters;
    private boolean hasTreasure;
    private Exit[] exits;
    private int xGridLocation;
    private int yGridLocation;
    private Random rand;

    Room(int levelheight, int levelwidth, int hwLimit) {
        rand = new Random();
        generateAndSetDimension(levelheight, levelwidth, hwLimit);
        isLit = fiatLux();
        hasTreasure = setTreasureChance();
        numMonsters = setNumberMonsters();
        exits = new Exit[howManyExits()];
    }

    public void setXLocation(int x) {
        xGridLocation = x;
    }

    public void setYLocation(int y) {
        yGridLocation = y;
    }

    public int getXLocation() {
        return xGridLocation;
    }

    public int getYLocation() {
        return yGridLocation;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    //3 or 4 max exits is reasonable
    private int howManyExits() {
        return rand.nextInt(3) + 1; //must return at least 1
    }

    //this can and should return 0 frequently,
    //not every room should be an encounter!
    //again, magic number for now
    //a one-in-six chance there will be monsters at all
    private int setNumberMonsters() {
        int r = rand.nextInt(7);
        if((r%6) == 0) {
            return rand.nextInt(7);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getNumberMonsters() {
        return numMonsters;
    }

    //magic number for now
    //want smallish chance of a treasure in the room
    private boolean setTreasureChance() {
        return (rand.nextInt(14)%13 == 0);
    }

    public boolean getTreasureChance() {
        return hasTreasure;
    }

    public boolean getLightedState() {
        return isLit;
    }

    //magic number for now
    //want approximately even chances of a light or dark room
    private boolean fiatLux() {
        return (rand.nextInt(100)%2 == 0);
    }

    //prefer to generate room's height and width together to easily
    //check resulting proportions, thus write results to member fields as a side effect
    private void generateAndSetDimension(int levelheight, int levelwidth, int hwLimit) {
        int maxroomh = levelheight/hwLimit;
        int maxroomw = levelwidth/hwLimit;
        double bigger = 0.0;
        double smaller = 0.0;
        //room's proportions are acceptable if aspect ratio is <= 7
        do {
            height = rand.nextInt(maxroomh);
            if(height < MIN_ROOM_HEIGHT) {
                height = MIN_ROOM_HEIGHT;
            }
            width = rand.nextInt(maxroomw);
            if(width < MIN_ROOM_WIDTH) {
                width = MIN_ROOM_WIDTH;
            }
            bigger = height < width ? width : height;
            smaller = height < width ? height : width;
        } while((bigger/smaller) > 7.0);

    }
}
```

**Exit.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Exit {
    private boolean isDoor;
    private boolean isConcealed;
    private Exit pairedExit;
    private int xLocation;
    private int yLocation;
    Random rand;

    Exit(int x, int y, int doorbounds, int concealedbounds, int doorchance, int concealedchance) {
        rand = new Random();
        xLocation = x;
        yLocation = y;
        isDoor = randomizedDoor(doorbounds, doorchance);
        isConcealed = randomizedConcealment(concealedbounds, concealedchance);
    }

    public void pairOtherExit(Exit other) {
        pairedExit = other;
    }

    private boolean randomizedDoor(int upperbound, int chance) {
        return ((upperbound/chance) > rand.nextInt(upperbound)) ? true : false;
    }

    private boolean randomizedConcealment(int upperbound, int chance) {
        if(isDoor) { //concealed exits always only look like walls, never doors
            return false;
        } else { //the chance this exit might be concealed
            return ((upperbound/chance) > rand.nextInt(upperbound)) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

**DungeonLevel.java**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DungeonLevel {

    //set upper bounds of size of a dungeon level
    public static final int GRID_W_MAX = 100;
    public static final int GRID_H_MAX = 100;

    //set lower bounds of size of dungeon level
    public static final int GRID_MINIMUM = 40;

    private Random rand;
    private int gridW;
    private int gridH;
    public Room[] rooms;
    public List<Room> gettingRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

    //limits number of non-wall units so that the entire level
    //is not one big space, recommended is 1/2 of H*W
    private int roomCapacity;

    //controls size of room, recommended is 1/10 of H plus 1/10 of W
    private int roomSizeLimiter;

    private char[][] theGrid; //may convert to int later

    DungeonLevel() {
        rand = new Random();
        gridH = rand.nextInt(GRID_H_MAX - GRID_MINIMUM) + GRID_MINIMUM;
        gridW = rand.nextInt(GRID_W_MAX - GRID_MINIMUM) + GRID_MINIMUM;
        roomCapacity = (gridW * gridH)/2;
        roomSizeLimiter = (gridW/20) + (gridH/20);
        theGrid = new char[gridH][gridW]; //W = cols, H = rows
        for (int row = 0; row < theGrid.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < theGrid[row].length; col++) {
                theGrid[row][col] = 'X';
            }
        }
        buildAndPlaceRooms();
        rooms = gettingRooms.toArray(new Room[0]);
    }

    private void buildAndPlaceRooms() {
        Room temp;
        int temph;
        int tempw;
        while(roomCapacity > 0) {
            temp = new Room(gridH, gridW, roomSizeLimiter);
            temph = temp.getHeight();
            tempw = temp.getWidth();
            int randx = rand.nextInt(gridW - tempw - 1) + 1;
            int randy = rand.nextInt(gridH - temph - 1) + 1;
            temp.setXLocation(randx);
            temp.setYLocation(randy);           
            placeRoom(randx, randy, temph, tempw);
            roomCapacity -= (temph*tempw);
            gettingRooms.add(temp);
        }
    }

    private void placeRoom(int x, int y, int h, int w) {
        for(int row = y; row < y + h; row++) {
            for(int col = x; col < x + w; col++) {
                theGrid[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    public Room[] getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public int getDungeonHeight() {
        return gridH;
    }

    public int getDungeonWidth() {
        return gridW;
    }

    public void drawLevelInASCII() {
        for(int row = 0; row < theGrid.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < theGrid[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(theGrid[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**DrawnDungeon.java**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawnDungeon extends JPanel {

    //each unit on the grid has a certain size
    public static final int UNIT_SIZE = 7;

    private int dungeonheight;
    private int dungeonwidth;

    private Room[] r;

    DrawnDungeon(Room[] rarr, int h, int w) {
        r = rarr;
        dungeonheight = h*UNIT_SIZE;
        dungeonwidth = w*UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, dungeonwidth, dungeonheight);
        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            if(r[i].getLightedState()) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            }
            g.fillRect(r[i].getXLocation()*UNIT_SIZE, r[i].getYLocation()*UNIT_SIZE, 
                r[i].getWidth()*UNIT_SIZE, r[i].getHeight()*UNIT_SIZE);
            if(r[i].getTreasureChance()) {
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(UNIT_SIZE + r[i].getXLocation()*UNIT_SIZE, 
                       UNIT_SIZE + r[i].getYLocation()*UNIT_SIZE,
                       UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(UNIT_SIZE + r[i].getXLocation()*UNIT_SIZE, 
                       UNIT_SIZE + r[i].getYLocation()*UNIT_SIZE,
                       UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
            }
            if(r[i].getNumberMonsters() != 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawString((r[i].getNumberMonsters() + "M"), (r[i].getXLocation()*UNIT_SIZE)+UNIT_SIZE,
                    (r[i].getYLocation()*UNIT_SIZE) +UNIT_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Dungeon.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Dungeon extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    private Random rand;
    private DungeonLevel[] dlevels;
    private String[] levellabels;
    private DrawnDungeon[] drawnlevels;
    private JComboBox<String> cb;
    private JPanel cards;
    private JPanel holdcombobox;
    private JPanel holdall;

    Dungeon(int possibleNumOfLevels) {
        super("Random Dungeon");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,800);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        rand = new Random();
        dlevels = new DungeonLevel[rand.nextInt(possibleNumOfLevels) + 1];
        levellabels = new String[dlevels.length];
        drawnlevels = new DrawnDungeon[dlevels.length];
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750,750));
        generateLevels();
        holdall = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        holdcombobox = new JPanel();
        cb = new JComboBox<>(levellabels);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        holdcombobox.add(cb);
        holdall.add(holdcombobox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        holdall.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(holdall);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)cards.getLayout();
        cl.show(cards, (String)e.getItem());
    }

    private void generateLevels() {
        for(int i = 0; i < dlevels.length; i++) {
            dlevels[i] = new DungeonLevel();
            levellabels[i] = new String("Level" + (i+1));
            drawnlevels[i] = new DrawnDungeon(dlevels[i].getRooms(),
                dlevels[i].getDungeonHeight(), dlevels[i].getDungeonWidth());
            cards.add(drawnlevels[i], levellabels[i]);
        }
    }

    public void displayLevelMap(int whichlevel) {
        dlevels[whichlevel].drawLevelInASCII();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Dungeon dungeon = new Dungeon(5);
            //dungeon.displayLevelMap(0); //test
            dungeon.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @Martin Frank, thank you for your detailed review. I will go read all the links you posted to educate myself further.

Comment: (CR wouldn't let me edit other comment.) Also, I have two questions. 1) I now understand that I shouldn't have been multiplying UNIT_SIZE with other values repeatedly. What I don't quite get is what the problem with the yellow oval and dark gray outline is. I wanted a yellow oval with a dark gray outline. 2) I didn't see the "public" keyword for the Test class. Is it meant to be an inner class of the Room class? Again, thank you for all the detailed comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very nice code for a beginner, thank you very much for sharing. so some issues with your code i see:

### class `Exit`

well you have a place holder in your `Room` for instances of the `Exit` but you never create any instance of this class (no code with this expression:**`new Exit(...)**). So this class is not required - and if you intend to use it later i point to the clean code Pattern [YAGNI - Ya aint goona need it](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-5-blue/#You_Aint_Gonna_Need_It_YAGNI), so you could remove it as well.

### getter & setter

[TL'DR](https://dzone.com/articles/java-getter-and-setter-basics-common-mistakes-and): **getter** are methods for getting a variable value from an object, **setter** are used to set a value to a variable from an object.

so how to deal with this issue: `numMonsters = setNumberMonsters();` (it violates the getter/setter contract)?

you should use a proper name for the method: `adjustNumberMonsters();` and it should be a void method and a private method and only used in the constructor.

doing so your constructor would have a clear construction order:

```
private Random rand = new Random(); //move it out of the constructor to improve readability
Room(int levelheight, int levelwidth, int hwLimit) { 
        adjustSize(levelheight, levelwidth, hwLimit);
        adjustLightLevel();
        adjustTreasureChance();
        adjustNumberMonsters();
        //exits = new Exit[howManyExits()]; //remove it
}
```

now it's clear **to everyone** what the constructor does.

**NOTE:** as [mentioned here](https://towardsdatascience.com/are-void-methods-bad-6d67dedc6600) it's good to hide these methods, so they can not be called accidently.

### complexity

some methods are too complex (at least for me) so it might be useful to break these methods down. Worst part is the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. I suggest to create a separate method to draw a Room:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, dungeonwidth, dungeonheight);
    for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        //refactoring here: break it down into seperate methods
        drawRoom(g, r[i]);        
    }
}
```

**digging deeper here**

you re-calculate some values and this is neither performant nor readable

```
private void drawRoom(Graphics g, Room room){
    int x = room.getXLocation()*UNIT_SIZE;
    int y =  room.getYLocation()*UNIT_SIZE;
    int w = room.getWidth()*UNIT_SIZE;
    int h = room.getHeight()*UNIT_SIZE;
    g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    if(room.getTreasureChance()) {
        //the outline code is overpainted by the following code
        //g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        //g.fillOval(UNIT_SIZE + x, UNIT_SIZE + y, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
        
        //this code paints exactly over the exisiting drawing from above
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawOval(UNIT_SIZE + x, UNIT_SIZE + y, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
    }
    if(room.getNumberMonsters() != 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString((room.getNumberMonsters() + "M"), x + UNIT_SIZE, y + SIZE);
    }
```

### comments

instead of using comments it is way better to write tests to describe the behaviour. Here is an example that can be applied on various places in your code

```
class RoomTest{
    
    @Test
    validateRoomAspectRatio(){
        //given
        Room room = new Room(...);

        //when
        double aspect = room.width / room.height 

        //room's proportions are acceptable if aspect ratio is <= 7
        //then
        Assert.assertTrue(0.7 < aspect);
    }
}
```

### bugs

some of your code does not behave as expected

```
//this can and should return 0 frequently,
//not every room should be an encounter!
//again, magic number for now
//a one-in-six chance there will be monsters at all
private int setNumberMonsters() {
    int r = rand.nextInt(7);
    if((r%6) == 0) { //BUG: this is not 1 in 6
        return rand.nextInt(7);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this method does not provide a 1/6 chance but a 1/7 chance. And it is not very helpful to check on `modulo` - you should use a rteadable and robust code:

```
private int setNumberMonsters() {
    int r = rand.nextInt(6);
    return r == 0 ? rand.nextInt(7) : 0;
}
```